# strip entire polars dataframe

Tags: strip, python-polars

I want to strip leading and trailing whitespaces from a polars dataframe with this line of code:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["foo ", "ham", "spam ", "egg",],
        "L": ["A54", " A12", "B84", " C12"],

    }
)
print(df)

shape: (4, 2)
┌───────┬──────┐
│ A     ┆ L    │
│ ---   ┆ ---  │
│ str   ┆ str  │
╞═══════╪══════╡
│ foo   ┆ A54  │
│ ham   ┆  A12 │
│ spam  ┆ B84  │
│ egg   ┆  C12 │
└───────┴──────┘

df_clean = df.select(
            [pl.all().map(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)]
        )
```

But it did not work. How can I strip an entire polars dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.str.strip()` is deprecated now.

[`.str.strip_chars()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.str.strip_chars.html) should be used instead.

Answer (score 3):

There is corresponding method `.strip()` for *string* columns ([see doc](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.strip.html#polars.Expr.str.strip))

```py
df.select(pl.all().str.strip())
```

Also if you have columns with different data types - you can select only *string* columns by `pl.col(pl.Utf8)`:

```py
df.select(pl.col(pl.Utf8).str.strip())
```

Comment: `strip` has been depreciated since 0.19.3. Use `polars.Expr.str.strip_chars` instead.